# What's the difference between WSGI <app> and <module>?

Tags: python, uwsgi, wsgi

I followed these [instructions to serve Python (Web2Py) via uWSGI](http://www.web2pyslices.com/slice/show/1435/web2py-uwsgi-cherokee-on-ubuntu-1004). However, the web server returned an error:

> **uWSGI Error** 
>   Python application not found

until I modified the config.xml config file from:

```
<uwsgi>
    <pythonpath>/var/web2py/</pythonpath>
    <app mountpoint="/">
        <script>wsgihandler</script>
    </app>
</uwsgi>
```

to:

```
<uwsgi>
    <pythonpath>/var/web2py/</pythonpath>
    <module>wsgihandler</module>
</uwsgi>
```

**What's the difference between <app> and <module>? Why did <module> work, but not <app>?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the --app option is deprecated by more than a year (it should be reported in uWSGI logs if you use a stable version 1.2/1.4). For wsgi apps you use --module (for python modules) and --wsgi-file (for .wsgi files)

Comment: Not seeing a deprecation message in logs, just failure as OP noted with --version 1.2.3-debian (ubuntu 13.04 x86_64), and plenty of outdated documentation showing that erroneous form still.